# usage of "Not that"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction

Can I use "**Not that**" in the following context?

> "Students have to learn concepts deeply, **not that** [they] just
> memorize them."

Can I use another phrase instead of "Not that"?

Comment: No - _not_ on its own is sufficient. _That_ would serve  no function in the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of construction is called [parallelism](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/parallelism/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIzI_Nz5TQ7gIViDArCh1tlgJEEAAYASAAEgKshPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds), where the beginning of one sentence is considered to apply to subsequent partial sentences. This is a corrected version of your sentence:

> separate sentences:
> Students have to learn concepts deeply.
> [Students have to] not just memorize them.
>
> paralleled sentence:
> Students have to learn concepts deeply, not just memorize them.

If we take apart your suggested sentence, this is what we get:

> Students have to learn concepts deeply.
> [Students have to] not that they just memorize them.

It is easy to see that, when you apply the first part of the first sentence to the partial sentence, you get something that doesn't make sense. Removing **they** doesn't help: you have to remove **that they** to make a proper sentence, as in my first example.

---

There are several verbs concerned with a situation or idea (for example know, think, consider) that require a that-clause. If you look up a verb in a [good dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/know), it will generally say whether a that-clause is possible.

> I think that we should wait until we have all the facts.

In addition, you can introduce a situation or idea using "it is".

> It is just/true/only/possible/not that...

Looking at the sentence in your comment

> It's not that.... it's just that...

There is no parallelism in this sentence, because it's not just the second part of each clause that's different: the first part of each clause is different too.

In a sentence with parallelism, there is generally **less** in the second clause than the first clause, so you wouldn't use a **that** in the second clause unless there's one in the first.. and even then, it can often be omitted as part of the parallelism, as in this example:

> It is important that students learn concepts deeply
> [It is important that students] not just memorize them
>
> It is important that students learn concepts deeply, not just memorize them

**not** is an adverb, and adverb positioning is flexible: most people would prefer the second version, so that the clause starts with **not**.

Comment: So, when do I have to use "that" in the structure of "not that"?  when does the subject of the second sentence differ from the first one? can you please explain that? I see structures like " It's not that ..., it's just...", and other similar ones.

Comment: I have updated my answer.